# React props not loading the datatable

Tags: reactjs

Initially while my page loads.
The props are 0 and later it is an array however the datable is not loaded even when the array is not empty

const [dataVar, setDataVar] = useState(props.details);

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezpjr.png)
[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTxiZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [dataVar, setDataVar] = useState();

React.useEffect(()=>{

   setDataVar[props.details]

},[])
```

The state must be changed to setState function

And it is not recommended to put props in the state value.

Comment: Looking good, I would add to your solution `const [dataVar, setDataVar] = useState();` on the top line.

Comment: Yes It worked thank you I had already tried it said too many rerenders and react has some limilation. Later I changed the dependencies to props.details and it worked.